# Wrong reference to Activity in listener after screen rotation

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a problem with the Google Maps Api. After I rotate the screen I have a wrong/old reference to the Activity. 
I"am using "mMapFragment.setRetainInstance(true);". "pact" is the Activity. The logging gives me the hascode of the activity but they are not the same(look example).

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

        if (map != null) {
            Log.d(H.TAG, "setUpMapifNeeded" );

            Log.d(H.TAG, pact.toString() + " set new onclicklistener");
            map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

                    Log.d(H.TAG, pact.toString() + " click");
                }
            });
        }

}
```

**Loggin example**

before rotation:

- MainApp@422fa1c0 MainApp Created
- MainApp@422fa1c0 set new onclicklistener
- MainApp@422fa1c0 click

after rotation:

- MainApp@42b291f0 MainApp Created
- MainApp@42b291f0 set new onclicklistener
- MainApp@**422fa1c0** click

Do you need more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i got it, the answer is to change the line

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.map_container, mMapFragment);
```

to

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.map_container, mMapFragment);
```

Answer (score 0):

onRetainInstance preserve the Fragment instance and not the Activity.
You need to update your Activity reference to the one passed to you in

```
onAttach(Activity)
```